# How to change style of a class inside Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change background color of my div using jQuery selector and I can't get it to work.

My [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Alexnotonfire/pen/EPKGxq).

**HTML**

```
<div class='demo'></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.demo {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('demo').style.backgroundColor = "black";
});
```

Comment: you are missing a `.` i.e. selector should be `$('.demo')` and instead of `style` you should use `css()` function.

Comment: Please search before posting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$('demo')` will return jquery object not a dom object also your selector is missing a `.`, use

```
 $('.demo').css('background-color ','black');
```

Reference: [jquery css() doc](http://api.jquery.com/css/).